# python same module in different file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, module

I have a MVC project and I would to import my module like that:

```
 import projet

 view = projet.view()

 controller = projet.controller()

 model = project.model()
```

but, I'd like that controller(), model() and view() are in different files.
How to do a module (project) but with different file in without import the other files after?

Comment: In `projet`, import the files with `view`, `controller`, and `model`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create directory named `project`, create file `__init__.py`in this dir, put there code:

```
from view import *
from controller import *
from model import *
```

To the same dir put your `view.py`, `controller.py`, `model.py`

When you do

```
import project
```

all other imports would be done automatically (from `__init__.py`). This is called packages (directory `project` will become package name, packages are detected by existence of `__init__.py`).

Further reading: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/Packages.html

Comment: Nice answer, but it might be even better with a link to [the tutorial section on packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) and/or some explanation of what a package is (or even just using the word).

Answer (score 2):

You could make a `project.py` file that looks like this:

```
from viewModule import view
from controllerModule import controller
from modelModule import model
```

Then your above code should work